Half-Bridge with ISC060N10NM6_L1 - LTspice "time step too small" error
Currently, I am simulating my half-bridge model in LTspice while using the  ISC060N10NM6_L1. However I am having an error ("time step too small").
I included my simulation model. What is causing that error from LTspice?



What are those rectangular boxes that say A/B and C/D on them?

@SteKulov Basically, they are Dc_link capacitors
